# How to improve interaction between Android Studio class and Processing sketch

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, processing

I have created an app in which there is a Processing Sketch being displayed on my  `MainActivity` :

```java
package app.yeah.app;

        import android.app.Fragment;
        import android.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Window;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

            TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
            //
            Fragment fragment;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager;

            //
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragment = new ProcMenu();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frag, fragment).commit();
            }
        }
```

By using the fragment, I display my Processing sketch:

```java
package app.yeah.app;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PVector;

public class ProcMenu extends PApplet
{
    PVector cur;
    float r;
    public void setup()
    {
        //size(240, 400);
        smooth();
        r = width / 20;
    }
    public void draw()
    {
        background(0);
        cur = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);

        fill(255, 0, 200, 200);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(cur.x, cur.y, r, r);

        fill(255, 200, 0);
        text("X: " + cur.x + ", Y: " + cur.y, r, r);
    }
}
```

The sketch easily displays the coordinates, that's great but, I want to be able to access such variables in my `MainActivity` an then displaying it on my `textView` t1. But in variables aren't updating, I don't know how to do it. 
The `textView` is on layout:

```java
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the variables from the `ProcMenu` class to the `MainActivity` class. There are two ways to do this:

**Approach 1:** Create a get function in your `ProcMenu` class that returns the coordinates, and just call that function from the `MainActivity` class whenever you want to update.

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
   ProcMenu fragment;

   public void updateText(){
      t1.setText(fragment.getCur().x + ", " + framgent.getCur().y);
   }
}

public class ProcMenu extends PApplet{
    PVector cur;

    public PVector getCur(){
       return cur;
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:** Create a set function in your `MainActivity` class, then pass your instance of `MainActivity` into your `ProcMenu` class. Then simply call the setter whenever you want to update.

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
   ProcMenu fragment = new ProcMenu(this);

   public void updateText(PVecotr cur){
      t1.setText(cur.x + ", " + cur.y);
   }
}

public class ProcMenu extends PApplet{
    PVector cur;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public ProcMenu(MainActivity mainActivity){
       this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public PVector updateCur(){
       mainActivity.updateText(cur);
    }
}
```

Which approach you take is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using Handler, there is the code:

In Activity:

Declare and assigne global variables

```
public static Handler sender = null;        
Handler receiver = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.e("Activity", "message received" + msg.obj);
        // Do Something.
    }
};
```

When setting sketch's fragment:

```
PApplet sketch = new Sketch(receiver);
```

To send data to sketch:

```
if (sender!=null)sender.obtainMessage(int what, Object data).sendToTarget();
```

In Sketch:
Declare and assigne global variables:

```
private static Handler mSender;
```

Sketch Constructor:

```
Sketch(Handler sender) {
        mSender = sender;
        SensorActivity.sender = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.e("Sketch", "message arrived");
                // Do Something.                        
            }
        };
}
```

To send data to Activity:

```
mSender.obtainMessage(int what, Object data).sendToTarget();
```